# Show properties in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, inequality, vectors

I want to show the following properties in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

- $2 \|x\|^2+2 \|y\|^2=\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2$
- $\|x-y\| \|x+y\|\leq \|x\|^2+ \|y\|^2$

I have tried the following:

- $$\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2=(x+y) \cdot (x+y)+(x-y) \cdot (x-y)=\|x\|^2$$
  $$+ x \cdot y+ y \cdot x+ \|y\|^2+ \|x\|^2-x \cdot y-y \cdot x+ \|y\|^2=2 \|x\|^2+ 2 \|y\|^2$$
- $\|x-y\| \|x+y\| \leq (\|x\|+\|y\|)^2=\|x\|^2+ 2 \|x\| \|y\|+\|y\|^2$

But the latter isn't $\leq \|x\|^2+ \|y\|^2$. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: You haven't done something wrong; you just found an upper bound that is too large.

Comment: Ok, and now can I show the desired bound? @AhmedHussein

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second inequality is true iff the squared inequality is true, i.e iff
$$\|x-y\|^2\|x+y\|^2\leq (\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)^2$$
You have
$$\|x-y\|^2\|x+y\|^2=(\|x\|^2-2(x,y)+\|y\|^2)(\|x\|^2+2(x,y)+\|y\|^2)=(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)^2-4(x,y)^2\leq (\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)^2$$
Now if you are wandering why your inequality is correct, you can take square root of both sides of this inequality, because they are positive, and because the square root is monotonically increasing function.

Answer (score 2):

$$(\|x-y\|\|x+y\|)^2=(x-y)^2\cdot(x+y)^2$$ $$=(x^2-2xy+y^2)\cdot(x^2+2xy+y^2)$$
$$=x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4$$ I skipped a test in trivial calculation so show this in your workings. Now as $x^2$ and $y^2$ are always positive we find: $$(\|x-y\|\|x+y\|)^2\leq x^4+y^4=\|x\|^4+\|x\|^4$$ As both sides are positive and $\sqrt{t}$ is monotone increasing on that interval then $$\|x-y\|\|x+y\|\leq \sqrt{\|x\|^4+\|x\|^4}\leq \sqrt{\|x\|^4}+\sqrt{\|y\|^4}$$
Then you are done. The last inequality follows from an inequality involving the sum of square roots. It's simple enough to prove so I'll leave that to you if you have not encountered it before.

EDIT:
Notice that 
$$(\|x-y\|\|x+y\|)^2=(x-y)^2\cdot(x+y)^2=\big((x-y)(x+y)\big)^2$$ 
$$=(x^2-y^2)^2=(\|x\|^2-\|y\|^2)^2\leq (\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)^2$$
which leads directly to the result using the logic as shown above.

Comment: You can simplify a lot, if you spot the formula $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$ on the second line.

Comment: @Svetoslav I rolled back because it seems that you and I actually saw different things from your observation. Thanks for the hint though.

Comment: But by Cauchy Schwartz inequality $\|x-y\|^2\|x+y\|^2\ge \langle x-y,x+y\rangle ^2$ always and the equality is achieved iff $x-y=\lambda(x+y)$ which need not be the case.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^n$ does my equality not hold true though as the norm is defined as $\|x\|=\sqrt{x\cdot x}$?

Comment: I wanted to say that the equality $(x-y)^2(x+y)^2=((x-y).(x+y))^2$ is not true for all $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$. It is only true in $\mathbb R^1$.

Comment: I thought the dot product was commutative in $\mathbb{R}^n$ though? So $(x-y)\cdot (x-y) \cdot (x+y) \cdot (x+y)= (x-y) \cdot (x+y) \cdot (x-y) \cdot (x+y)$? This [site](http://www.auburn.edu/~harriga/mh6010/pdf/dotProduct.pdf) seems to support commutivity in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 1):

The first is ok. The second is flawed (at least, I don't see the inequality you use there). Square the inequality and prove this.

EDIT: The second "proof" isn't flawed. The OP just used the triangle inequality here two times (see the comments below).

Comment: The second just obtains an upper bound higher than desired, the methodology getting to that upper bound is fine. The OP just used the triangle inequality on both products.

Comment: Aha. Then please tell me how one can see the inequality he/she uses there. It is correct, sure, but it is not immediate.

Comment: @K.Power Do you have an idea how I can get the desired upper bound?

Comment: I said it: Square the inequality and prove this. It's easy.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Can we square the inequality since at both sides there are positive numbers?

Comment: Exactly, Evinda.

Comment: So you mean that we assume that the inequality holds? Or could we maybe also square only the left side of the inequality and then get the square of the desired upper bound?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp as norms are always positive both products are positive, so we can use the triangle inequality freely. So $||x-y||||x+y||\leq (||x||+||y||)(||x||+||y||)$

Comment: K. Power: Alright, thanks. @Evinda: The inequality holds if and only if it holds with both sides squared. You gave the reason for that. Now, take the squared LHS and do similarly as in part one. You will quickly see that it is not larger than the squared RHS.